# Why elements move when i hovered on anything (Only With IE6)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Take a look :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSmqTdQK3Tk

http://www.faressoft.org/BlueCristalTheme/

Comment: +1 for building a video describing the problem and uploading it on youtube. But some relevant HTML needs to be here too

Comment: My code is here : http://www.faressoft.org/BlueCristalTheme/

Comment: I would however add some introductory text which summarizes the problem instead of plain posting two links before this question get closed as "No real question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 6 requires hasLayout to be set to true.
Various ways are used to give elements 'true' hasLayout. Some don't affect your design at all.

Try giving your footer, navigation, and main panels a zoom or 1, with the following:

```
#footer,#main,#nav { zoom: 1; }
```

If that doesn't work, change `zoom: 1;` to

```
height: 1%
```

That should fix things.

Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure ! it did not succeed :( I tried #footer,#main,#nav { zoom: 1; } and #footer,#main,#nav { height: 1%; } and #footer,#main,#nav { zoom: 1; height: 1%; } but nothings changed !

Comment: Thank you very much :) This .box { zoom: 1; } helped me.
But What Exactly Does it Do ?

Comment: Glad it worked. Trying to explain what it exactly does is a little sketchy. But like I said, IE6 requires hasLayout to be set to true. Therefore, by giving your box with class .box a zoom of 1, you're giving setting it's hasLayout to true, thereby fixing a lot of potential IE6 bugs. IE6 sucks. I dropped IE6 compatibility on my site. I just don't care anymore :)

Comment: And by the way, in my comment, I was guessing on your DIV id's. That's why it didn't work and only worked when you applied it to an actual DIV (.box). lol, I should've looked at your code before I answered. Oh well.